# Kendo Grid Mobile with JSP Wrappers

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, jsp-tags

I cannot get the mobile Adaptive Grid features to work using the Kendo JSP wrappers. I have cut everything down as much as possible, and it will not work with the wrappers. I can get everything working perfectly fine with Javascript. The following works perfectly fine:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    var gridConfig = {
        columns: [
            {field: "name", title: "Name"},
            {field: "age", title: "Age"}
        ],
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        mobile: true
    };

    $("#grid").kendoGrid(gridConfig);
</script>
```

When I look at the grid in a desktop browser, my filter and column menus appear as you would expect. When I view the grid on my cell phone, the filter and column menus push the grid aside and appear as a standard mobile selection list. If I create the same grid using the JSP wrappers, it doesn't work:

```
<div id="grid">
    <kendo:grid name="grid" filterable="true" columnMenu="true" mobile="true" >
        <kendo:grid-columns>
            <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name" />
            <kendo:grid-column title="Age" field="age" />
        </kendo:grid-columns>
    </kendo:grid>
</div>
```

The filter and column menus display on my phone as they do on the desktop, which makes them unusable since they slide off the viewing area and disappear when I try to scroll to them.

I know the obvious question is why bother with the Wrappers, but I have to due to our usage of Freemarker throughout the application.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I dug around on my page and I think I found the source of the problem. My wrappers are converted to javascript as expected, but the result is the following: 
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({"filterable":true,"columns":[{"filterable":true,"field":"name","title":"Name","menu":true},{"filterable":true,"field":"age","title":"Age","menu":true}],"columnMenu":true,"mobile":"true"});})
The mobile flag is expressed as text. It's not converted to a boolean, like the other boolean flags are. Can the conversion be forced? The docs say it's either a boolean or text, but I need a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Had to just modify the source of the latest release (2016.1.112) myself. In case anyone else has a similar issue, adjust the setMobile method of com.kendoui.taglib.GridTag.java.

```
public void setMobile(java.lang.Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String && (((String)value).equalsIgnoreCase("true") || ((String)value).equalsIgnoreCase("false"))) {
        setProperty("mobile", Boolean.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    else {
        setProperty("mobile", value);
    }
}
```

Could be better, but it's functional and does what I need for now.